# Not able to get the stored Local User when authenticated through federated Google Authentication when enabling Email as username feature

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using wso2 identity server 6.1 version, I've made all the configurations for Google Federated Authentication, and below is the URL which I'm calling from Client Application
String googleIdp="https://wso2-is:port/oauth2/authorize?client_id="+client_id+"&response_type=code&scope=openid email profile&redirect_uri="+redirect_uri+"&state="+state+"&idpType=google";

Now when i call this URL, I'm getting successfully authenticated by google and

1. when the user is available in wso2 identity server, I'm letting the User to login directly after succesful federated google Authentication
2. When the user is not available in wso2 identity server, I'm redirecting the user to registration page so that the the user can self register himself after successful federated Google Authentication. This is absolutely working fine with normal username.
   But the problem here is when I have enabled email as the username feature according to wso2 is docs, I'm able to get the federated authenticated username, but when i call the getUniqueUserWithClaimValues(claimMap, "carbon.super"); and pass the claimMap value according to the authentication script below, I'm getting the stored value as null even if the user is present in Identity server.
   I'm not using any tenant in identity server.
   My authentication steps are :
   Step 1 : username & password (Basic authentication)
   Step 2 : Federated Authtnication (Google) and below is my authentication script.
   Can anyone please help here, any help would be highly appreciated.

```
var client_id='';
var redirect_uri='';
var state='';
var errorPageParameters = {
    'status': 'Unauthorized',
    'statusMsg': 'You need to have a local user association to login to this application.'
};

// The local claims.
var MAPPED_FEDERATED_USER_NAME_CLAIM = "http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress";
var fedUser;

var onLoginRequest = function(context) {
    if(context.request.params && context.request.params.client_id!=null ){
        Log.info('client_id | {}'+context.request.params.client_id[0]);
        client_id=context.request.params.client_id[0];
    }
        if(context.request.params && context.request.params.redirect_uri!=null ){
        Log.info('redirect_uri | {}'+context.request.params.redirect_uri[0]);
        redirect_uri=context.request.params.redirect_uri[0];
    }
        if(context.request.params && context.request.params.state!=null ){
        Log.info('state | {}'+context.request.params.state[0]);
        state=context.request.params.state[0];
    }
    
    executeStep(1,{
        onSuccess: function(context){
            
        },
        onFail:function(context){
            if(context.request.params && context.request.params.idpType!=null && context.request.params.idpType[0]=='google'){
                 executeStep(2,{
                     onSuccess: function (context) {
                         if (context.currentKnownSubject.userStoreDomain == null) {
                             fedUser = context.currentKnownSubject;
                             var federatedUserName = context.currentKnownSubject.username;
                             Log.info("Federated authenticator | {} Google & Authenticated federated user is | {}"+ federatedUserName);
                             
                             // Filter the Users based on the federated username.
                              var claimMap = {};
                              claimMap["http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress"] = fedUser.remoteClaims.email;
                              
                              var storedLocalUser = getUniqueUserWithClaimValues(claimMap, "carbon.super");
                              Log.info("storedLocalUser | {}"+storedLocalUser);
                              if(storedLocalUser != null){
                                  Log.info('username:: '+storedLocalUser.username);
                              }
                              else{
                                 var errorPage = 'https://<wso2is:port>/accountrecoveryendpoint/register.do?client_id='+client_id+'&response_type=code&scope=openid%20email%20profile%20phone&redirect_uri='+redirect_uri+'&state='+state;
                                   sendError(errorPage, errorPageParameters);
                              }
                         }
                     },
                     onFail: function(context){
                    }
                 });
             }
        }
    });
    
};
```

Comment: Could you please try `var storedLocalUser = getUniqueUserWithClaimValues(claimMap, context);`
as mentioned in the doc https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/references/adaptive-authentication-js-api-reference/#:~:text=var%20mappedUsername%20%3D%20getUniqueUserWithClaimValues(claimMap%2C%20context)%3B

Comment: Hi @Anuradha Karunarathna, that doesn't seem to work getting TypeError: cannot.get.default.number, can u please help with any other option

Comment: Hi @Anuradha Karunarathna, please help here with any other options